# How to Convert a List of Dataframes to a List of Lists?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I want to change a list of dataframes to a list of lists to be able to add and remove elements from the dataframes.I want to end up with something like:

Example:

```
> list <- list(list("p"=runif(5),
                    "n"=round(1000*rnorm(5,5,2))),
               list("p"=runif(10),
                    "n"=round(1000*rnorm(10,5,2))),
               list("p"=runif(15),
                    "n"=round(1000*rnorm(15,5,2)))
)
> class(list[[1]])
[1] "list"
```

Comment: Your reason for doing is not explained well.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question isn't clear enough to me, I guess you have something like this:

```
List  <- list(data.frame(a=1:4, b=4:1),
      data.frame(A=2:6, B=6:2))
```

which is a list of data.frames and you wnat it to be a list:

```
unlist(lapply(List, as.list), recursive=FALSE)
```

Or a list of lists

```
lapply(List, as.list)
```

Answer (score 1):

A data.frame is actually a list. You just have to remove the class.

```
mylist <- list(df1=data.frame(a=1:10, b=11:20),df2=data.frame(a=c("a","b"), b=c("c","d")))
str(mylist)
# List of 2
# $ df1:'data.frame':  10 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ a: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# ..$ b: int [1:10] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
# $ df2:'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ a: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 2
# ..$ b: Factor w/ 2 levels "c","d": 1 2

mylist2 <- lapply(mylist, unclass)
str(mylist2)
# List of 2
# $ df1:List of 2
# ..$ a: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# ..$ b: int [1:10] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
# ..- attr(*, "row.names")= int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# $ df2:List of 2
# ..$ a: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 2
# ..$ b: Factor w/ 2 levels "c","d": 1 2
# ..- attr(*, "row.names")= int [1:2] 1 2
```